# Git merge with a single dash

Tags: git, git-merge

I know that the command `git checkout -` checks you out to the previous *active branch* or *detached HEAD*.

What I would like to know is if the command `git merge -` merges the previous *active branch* or *detached HEAD* to my currently checked out *branch*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your assumption is correct and `git merge -` merges the *branch/commit checked out before the current one* into your currently checked out branch.

**The release notes for [Git 1.7.6](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.6.txt#L84) explicitly state this:**

> `git merge` learned `-` as a short-hand for *the previous branch*, just like the way `git checkout -` works.

In commands that allow this, `-` is a shorthand for `@{-1}` which is specified in [*gitrevisions*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-em-ltngtemegem-1em):

> `@{-<n>}, e.g. @{-1}`
> The construct `@{-<n>}` means the <n>th branch/commit checked out before the current one.

---

By looking through the release notes and the source code, I was able to identify the following commands that support a lone `-` as a short hand for `@{-1}`:

- git-checkout (since Git 1.6.2)
- git-merge (since Git 1.7.6)
- git-rebase (since Git 2.0.0)
- git-switch
- git-worktree
- git-revert
- git-cherry-pick

Comment: This is the missing link to documentation I was looking for. I've voted for this answer, as it's better than mine.

Comment: @DominicCronin To be honest, it was difficult choosing between yours and Matt's answer. I chose this answer since he also mentioned other commands that the `-` can also be used.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation for git-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-ltbranchgt) describes how you can describe the branch you want using the `@{-N}` syntax:

> You can use the @{-N} syntax to refer to the N-th last branch/commit checked out using "git checkout" operation. You may also specify - which is synonymous to @{-1}.

So far I haven't found any other documentation that says `-` is synonymous with `@{-1}`, but this notation is documented in [git-revisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-em-ltngtemegem-1em) which means that it's more general than just for use with `git checkout`. It seems reasonable to think you can use it whereever a branch or commit is required.

I habitually use both `git checkout -` and `git merge -`. They are very useful, and I've never had a problem with either of them. So to answer your question directly, yes, `git merge` interprets `-` just like `git checkout`. That said, it's a shame the documentation is so arcane.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and the merge is done with the last active branch

Comment: I tested it as well and it seems to do exactly that. However, I am curious if this is the **rule**.

Answer (score 0):

other answers give correct pointers to the documentation, here is how it is currently (version 2.32) implemented :

`git` scans the reflog for the latest line looking like :

```
checkout: moving from xxx to yyy
```

and uses `xxx` as the target reference.

`@{-2}` searches for the second latest line, `@{-3}` for the third latest line, etc ...

---

You can try it on a test repo : the reflog for `HEAD` is simply a file stored at `.git/logs/HEAD`.

Note that, in that file, lines are written in chronological order : the oldest line is at the top, the most recent at the bottom. This is the reverse of what you see when you run `git reflog`, where the oldest line is at the bottom and the most recent at the top.

If you edit it (*warning* : editing the reflog by hand can break things, do this on a test repo, not on your main working repository), and change the the messages for the last `checkout: ...` line, you will see that commands such as `git checkout -` or `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{-XX}` change behavior accordingly.